# Rstudio installation on Ubuntu 17.04: Error: Cannot satisfy dependencies

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-17.04

I have R installed:

```
$ R

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

And now I am trying to install RStudio. I have downloaded the .deb from their site https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/:

```
rstudio-1.0.143-i386.deb
```

But I get an error:

```
Status: Error: Cannot satisfy dependencies.
```

What else should I install before installing Rstudio then?

Comment: You appear to be running the 64 bit version of R, and installing the 32 bit version of R Studio.  So I'd suggest first off you try the 64 bit of R Studio.  If that doesn't work, then run `dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb` in a terminal, it should complain about which dependencies it cannot satisfy - if you can't clear it up from there, add the output to your question.

Comment: @GregHNZ i have to install `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64.deb` and `libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb` as the dependencies. this should have been mentioned in their website!

Answer (score 0):

I installed Rstudio 1.0.136 using Anaconda Navigator. Very easy. point & click.

Answer (score 0):

Have faced a similar situation. Followed instructions from below link, hopefully it will resolve the issue.
http://www.samhillman.com/2017-04-15-rstudio/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what error your getting. I needed to install the following (might need `sudo`):

`apt-get install libjpeg62`